# Finding sequence of the last numeric value in a varchar variable

Tags: sql-server

I have a column in a table which has incremented values like:

```
AAA0000001
AAA0000002
```

... and so on

I want to find if the values stored in this column are in proper sequential order or if any value is missing in between or is deleted.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: What is your desired result/expected output?

Comment: the missing ids should be displayed in the output

Comment: Do you have records like `'AAB0000001'`, `'AAB0000002'` as well?

Comment: Does the values have consistent pattern? 10 characters, wherein the first 3 is alpha and the last 7 is numeric.

Comment: yes the first three characters are same always and the last 7 are numeric

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the pattern is always: `AAA[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]`, you can do this with a Tally Table.

Sample Data:

```
CREATE TABLE Tbl(val VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO Tbl VALUES
('AAA0000001'), ('AAA0000002'), ('AAA0000004'), ('AAA0000011');

val
----------
AAA0000001
AAA0000002
AAA0000004
AAA0000011
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/79df2/1/0)

```
;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        num = CAST(SUBSTRING(val, 4, LEN(val) - 3) AS INT)
    FROM Tbl
),
E1(N) AS(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
),
E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b),
E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b),
Tally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP(SELECT MAX(num) FROM Cte)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM E4
)
SELECT
    N, 
    val = 'AAA' + RIGHT('0000000' + CAST(N AS VARCHAR(7)), 7)
FROM Tally
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM Cte WHERE num = N
)
```

**RESULT**

```
N                    val
-------------------- ----------
3                    AAA0000003
5                    AAA0000005
6                    AAA0000006
7                    AAA0000007
8                    AAA0000008
9                    AAA0000009
10                   AAA0000010
```

---

Explanation:

1. The first `CTE`, named as `Cte`, extracts the numeric part of the strings and `CAST`s them to `INT`.
2. The succeeding `CTE`s, from `E1` to `Tally(N)` generates a table with sequential values from `1` up to the `MAX(num)` - the `INT` return from the first `CTE`.
3. The final `SELECT` just checks for the non-existing `num` from the first `CTE`.
4. `'AAA' + RIGHT('0000000' + CAST(N AS VARCHAR(7)), 7)` transforms `N` so that it follows the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Gaps problem. You can look into this article by Dwain Camps for more solutions on [Gaps and Islands](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/).

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` like this.

**Sample Data**

```
DECLARE @tab1 TABLE(id VARCHAR(20));

insert into @tab1 VALUES('AAA0000001'),('AAA0000002'),('AAA0000003'),('AAA0000004'),('AAA0000006'),('AAA0000007'),('AAA0000010');
```

**Query**

```
;WITH CTE as 
(
SELECT convert(int,STUFF(id,1,3,'')) id,convert(int,STUFF(id,1,3,'')) - ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY convert(int,STUFF(id,1,3,''))) rn
FROM @tab1
),CTE2 as 
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY rn) as rn, MIN(id) series_start,MAX(id) series_end
FROM CTE
GROUP BY rn
)
SELECT C2.series_end,C1.series_start
FROM CTE2 C1
INNER JOIN CTE2 C2 ON C1.rn = C2.rn + 1;
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e7a59/1)**

**Explanation**

- Output of CTE is the difference of gaps between id values.
- Output of CTE2 is the start and end of continuous series of numbers
- Final Output gives the start and end of gaps within the series

**Output**

```
series_end  series_start
4   6
7   10
```

Answer (score 1):

If the schema is fixed then no need for complex queries. This works:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( v VARCHAR(100) );

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 'AAA0000001' ),
        ( 'AAA0000002' ),
        ( 'AAA0000007' ),
        ( 'AAA0000008' ),
        ( 'AAA0000010' ),
        ( 'AAA0000011' ),
        ( 'AAA0000012' );


SELECT * FROM @t t1
CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 v FROM @t t2 WHERE t2.v > t1.v ORDER BY v) ca
WHERE RIGHT(t1.v, 7) <> RIGHT(ca.v, 7) - 1
```

Output:

```
v           v
AAA0000002  AAA0000007
AAA0000008  AAA0000010
```

Answer (score 0):

In sqlserver 2012, you can use [LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(LAG_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true) and [LEAD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(LEAD_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true)

```
DECLARE @t table(col1 varchar(15))
INSERT @t values('AAA0000001'),('AAA0000002'),('AAA0000004')

SELECT 
  case when 
    stuff(lag(col1) over (order by col1), 1,3,'') + 1 
      = stuff(col1, 1,3,'') then 'Yes' else 'No' end previous_exists,
  case when
    stuff(lead(col1) over (order by col1), 1,3,'') - 1 
      = stuff(col1, 1,3,'') then 'Yes' else 'No' end next_exists,
  col1
FROM @t
```

Result:

```
previous_exists  next_exists  col1
No               Yes          AAA0000001
Yes              No           AAA0000002
No               No           AAA0000004
```